# How to implement a mongodb connection over https with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got the following code, I will also manage a sign up/login part in the web application.

If I want to work over a secured connection,(so encryption wouldn't be needed so far in the application but in the mongo database?) how can I *add* the https?

```
var express = require ("express");
var mongodb = require ("mongodb");

var servidor = new express();
var BSON = mongodb.BSONPure;

servidor.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
servidor.use(express.bodyParser());

var cliente_mongo = mongodb.MongoClient;

cliente_mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost/campusero", function (err, db) {

    if (err) {
        console.log("Error de conexión "+err);
    } else {

        console.log("Connected to database");

    }

    servidor.listen(8080);

});
```

Comment: It's a bit strange that credentials would pass in the clear on the Internet, but in a secure data center, they're encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers communicate using TCP/IP sockets. Therefore, you must enable encrypted communication via SSL. I've provided links below describing the procedure (includes syntax for the native node.js driver). SSL will have to be enabled in your MongoDB environment, and SSL options have to be enabled in your application as it interfaces with the the driver.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-sslclients/

Comment: Worth noting that the community version requires you to build SSL functionality into your own binaries. If you want this pre-built, you require the Enterprise edition.